# Magento Move attributes.phtml

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

i need to remove short description in the view.phtml and replace with attribute.phtml tab...how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You should read your question before posting it and try to visualize how other people would understand it and if they really know where , what and why your view.phtml exists and same goes against attribute.phtml. it's also a good idea to give hints about what you are trying to accomplish. Currently nobody is able to understand it and this leads to the fact that nobody can advise you or answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your theme's `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` (not the base theme's, that can get overwritten) and replace this:

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
    <div class="short-description">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

with this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
```

And further down where you see the same line delete it. This avoids duplication.